# A specific question about Ignite RDD query in the example

Tags: sql, rdd, ignite

Going thru Ignite documents and samples, in SharedRDDExample.java, there is a query like below,

```
Dataset df = sharedRDD.sql("select _val from Integer where _key < 9");
```

My dumb question is: how would this query work, as "Integer" is not a table but a data type?  I must have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

By default, table name equals value type name, case insensitive (ALLCAPS). More precisely, it is `"cacheName".TYPEALLCAPS`. But you have default schema set in this case.

There are all kinds of ways to tune it [according to the doc](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/indexes#section-annotation-based-configuration).